# Objective-C, counting zombies via instruments, clarification needed

Tags: xcode4, instruments

As i was working on my program, i noticed that, upon profiling, instruments was nice enough to point me to a Zombie object when it saw one. Does the fact that this message does not show up indicative of the fact that app contains no zombie processes?

Is there a way i can **confirm** that app contains no references to Zombie processes?

In my question, i am explicitly mentioning Xcode4, as i have not seen automatic Zombie behavior in 3 and suspect it may be a new feature.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No zombie messages showing up is a good sign. It means you weren't accessing any freed objects while Instruments was tracing. There's no way for Instruments to confirm that your application never accesses a freed object. All Instruments can do is tell you when you access a freed object.

Regarding automatic zombie behavior, detecting zombies is not new behavior in Xcode 4. Instruments has a Zombies template in both Xcode 3.2 and 4 that detects zombies. You can also configure the Allocations instrument to detect zombies by clicking the Info button next to the instrument, which the zombie message is blocking in your screenshot.